# I have an ATI Radeon HD 6300 series video card; what do I use, radeon or radeonhd driver?

Tags: debian, drivers, video

I want to install the correct driver for my video card under Debian and I don't know which to install, xserver-xorg-video-radeon or xserver-xorg-video-radeonhd?

I've also read some of the documentation of the [package](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/xserver-xorg-video-radeonhd) and it mentions AMD/ATI Radeon r5xx, r6xx and r7xx families of chipsets. And I don't know what chipset family Radeon HD 6300 is under.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [X.org](http://www.x.org/wiki/Home), the [radeon](http://www.x.org/wiki/radeon) driver is [generally preferred](http://www.x.org/wiki/radeonhd#line-9) over the [radeonhd](http://www.x.org/wiki/radeonhd) driver.  [This table](http://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature#Decoderringforengineeringvsmarketingnames) says that you have an Evergreen chip.  (That page also shows what features are implemented in the radeon driver for your chipset.)

Comment: Based on the links you gave, Evergreen is still all TODO under **radeonhd** so it's a no go for that driver (for now).

Comment: radeon is still actively developed and maintained, while radeonhd has gone defunct and is no longer updated.   (Last commit to radeonhd git was over a year ago.)

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://kmuto.jp/debian/hcl and paste the output of `lspci -n` as asked. You will get the driver recommendations.

You may also just check if/how each driver works for you - nothing will explode because of it :)

Answer (score 0):

Xorg will detect automatically the correct driver for your graphics card (which I think is radeon). Use Debian testing, your chipset is too new for the stable version.

Answer (score 0):

1. Radeon HD 6300M, is in the evergreen family.  It is considered a separate family from the rXXX families.
2. *Generally* it is always preferred to use the `radeon` over the deprecated `radeonhd`.  There are exceptions, but unless you have a specific reason, `radeon` is the preferred driver.
3. FOSS evergreen support is *usable*, but it's still not as mature as the r6XX and r7XX series cards.  AMD has been actively working on FOSS drivers, to better support the newer families.  As is the usual case, updates take time trickling down to distro repositories.
4. It is your *option* to consider using the official binary FGLRX catalyst driver, which is available from the AMD driver site or Debian non-free repositories.  always try the repository first, if it does not work, then consider downloading the official AMD FGLRX installer.  In the usual cases, the proprietary driver offers significantly improved performance.  It also often has support for additional features, which *might* not be currently available in the FOSS `radeon` driver.

Either way, I would suggest you verify your acceleration is working as expected.
First check for OpenGL Direct Rendering, with this command.

```
glxinfo | grep rendering
## Expected response 'direct rendering: Yes'
```

Next check for XV Video Overlay, with this command

```
xvinfo -short
## Expected response, 'Adaptor #0: ...'
```

If you are missing these tools, they are available in the `mesa-utils` package.